# Extracting string between 2 characters from Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with entries like:
Hello [World]. I am trying to extract 'World' and make a new column with that, and doing this for every row.

Not sure how to go about this, I am not familar with Regex.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract part of a string in Pandas column and make a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935149/how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-in-pandas-column-and-make-a-new-column)

Comment: can you add a code example of input and what you expect to be the output?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['hello [world]'],['something [else]']], columns=['words']);
df['words'] = df['words'].str.replace('^.*\[|\]$','')

print(df)
```

The only complicated part there is that regex: `replace('.*\[|\]$','')`. That says to look for the start of the word `^` up to `.*` the first instance of `[` character OR `|` from the first instance of `]` character that is at the end of the string `$` and replace that with nothing `''`

If you are going to be doing this kind of thing often, I would highly encourage you to learn regex.